# Raspberry Pi 4 Camera video not working but image are

Tags: camera, pi-4, raspivid

https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-picamera/4

The error is persistent using the CLI

```
raspivid -o Desktop/video.h264
```

and with python

```
camera.start_preview()
camera.start_recording('/home/pi/Desktop/video.h264')
sleep(5)
camera.stop_recording()
camera.stop_preview()
```

Still images are working perfectly....
What in the heck is going on ?

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: What persisting error on the command line?

Comment: Hello and welcome – Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.